# Setting the timezone of a pandas datetime64 column to another column

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas `DataFrame` with a `datetime64` column and a column representing the timezone:

```
dates_df = pandas.read_json("""[{"event_time": "2023-04-03T15:03:52", "event_tz": "EDT"}, {"event_time": "2023-04-03T15:03:52", "event_tz": "EDT"}]""")
```

**How can the timezone of the `event_time` column be overwritten with the timezone specified in the `event_tz` column?**

The `tz_localize` and `tz_convert` functions of the datetime column seem to only accept single values, as opposed to a `Series`.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(dates_df['event_time'].astype(str) + " " + dates_df['event_tz'])` seems to work fine. Add `utc=True` in the case you have multiple timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion in the comments:

```
pd.to_datetime(dates_df['event_time'].astype(str) + " " + dates_df['event_tz'])
```